# download zip file as html while loadtesting

Tags: jmeter, download

I'm trying do loadtest for download zip file through jmeter.
I'm using save response to file to save results.
For 100 users all are getting downloaded with full file size.
when I trying to increase users to 200 some users are getting downloaded file as .html extension(not with full file size).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given you can successfully run your test @ 100 users and getting errors @ 200 my expectation is that your application gets overloaded and responds with error rather than with .zip file so:

1. First of all open downloaded .html file with a browser and see if you can figure out the cause from it.
2. Check response code and response message for these "failed" requests using i.e. [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
3. Check logs on the application under test side
4. Consider monitoring main health metrics on the application under test side (i.e. CPU, RAM, Swap, Disk, Network, free space, etc.), you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this
5. If after above steps you're still uncertain with regards to failures cause inspect your application infrastructure configuration (it might be the case that application/web server or database simply don't allow more than i.e. 150 connections) and/or use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to identify slowest components, largest objects, heaviest queries, etc.

Comment: Showing connection time out in view results tree for some requests